# What information will someone need to give me money?

Tags: exchanges

I want to use BitCoin to earn money from someone else for working for them.
I want to give them as little information about me as possible

What will I HAVE to give them so I can accept money, what personal info will have to be given?

Answer (score 9):

Bitcoin relies on disclosing as little information about yourself as needed in order to accomplish its functions. In order to receive coins, you only need to provide a Bitcoin address, like such:

1Br7vQZjkrJxhQEALt4ReL9hTqvQj4Xqge

If you are worried about your anonymity, you should generate a new address in the standard client that you will use only once. Should anyone wish for you to confirm that you own a given address, you can use the private key you have to [sign some meaningful message](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=70911.0).

Note however, that it is possible to try [connecting your Bitcoin address to your online identity](http://anonymity-in-bitcoin.blogspot.ca/2011/07/bitcoin-is-not-anonymous.html) if you are not careful. It is very unlikely, unless someone REALLY wants to find out who you are.

Comment: @Matthew You're welcome. This is what this website is for.

Comment: And to make it so the sender would really have a really hard time knowing anything more about you, use an hosted ewallet that delinks your incoming revenue transaction to your spend transaction.  

InstaWallet is one, for instance.

Comment: Just remember that if you use an online wallet like that, you are trusting them with your money. If you're paranoid, don't leave your money in an online wallet for longer than you need to.